# Chinese Checker C# in Unity. Connecting neighbour tiles

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

im a student currently stuck with an assignment, to create the game Chinese checkers. What Im trying to do now is to let every **tile** know its surrounding **neighbour** and what **direction** that **neighbour** is. Code wise, this is what I got :

```
    public class BoardSpawn : MonoBehaviour
    {

    [SerializeField]
    GameObject tiles, pawn;

    [SerializeField]
    float offset;
    //Skapar en jagged array av spelobjekt.
    GameObject[][] board = new GameObject[17][];
    TileScript[][] virtualBoard = new TileScript[17][];

    int[] upperOffset = new int[] { 1, 1, 1, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, -4, 0, 0, 0 };

    int[] lowerOffset = new int[] { 0, 0, 0, -4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 1, 1, 1 };


    //Längden på raden. 
    int[] rowLengths = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 4, 3, 2, 1 };

    void Start()
    {
        SpawnThisBoard();
        SetNeighbours();

    }

    // spawning the board with for in for loop 
    void SpawnThisBoard()
    {// loops through the row
        for (int i = 0; i < board.Length; i++)
        {
            board[i] = new GameObject[rowLengths[i]];
            virtualBoard[i] = new TileScript[rowLengths[i]];
            //loops through the column
            for (int j = 0; j < board[i].Length; j++)
            {
     // Creates a tile for each index position for the current row
                GameObject tile = Instantiate(tiles, new Vector3((-(rowLengths[i] - 1) + (offset * j)), 0f, offset * (8 - i)), Quaternion.identity);
                virtualBoard[i][j] = tile.GetComponent<TileScript>();

                virtualBoard[i][j].AssignIndex(j, i);
                // Just a switch to give certian positions a color
                switch (i)
                {
                    case 0:
                    case 1:
                    case 2:
                    case 3:
                        virtualBoard[i][j].SetColor(yellow);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                    case 5:
                    case 6:
                    case 7:
                        if (j < board[i].Length - 9)
                        {
                            virtualBoard[i][j].SetColor(blue);

                        }
                        else if (j > 8)
                        {
                            virtualBoard[i][j].SetColor(red);
                        }
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        break;
                    case 9:
                    case 10:
                    case 11:
                    case 12:
                        if (j < board[i].Length - 9)
                        {
                            virtualBoard[i][j].SetColor(green);

                        }
                        else if (j > 8)
                        {
                            virtualBoard[i][j].SetColor(black);
                        }

                        break;

                    case 13:
                    case 14:
                    case 15:
                    case 16:
                        virtualBoard[i][j].SetColor(white);
                        break;



                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

    }
    // gives position and direction to each tile 
    void SetNeighbours()
    {
        int test = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < virtualBoard.Length; i++)
        {
            int min = 0, max = 0, rowOffset = 0;
            switch (i)
            {
                case 1:
                case 2:
                case 3:
                    max = virtualBoard[i].Length - 1;
                    break;
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < virtualBoard[i].Length; j++)
            {
//If its not the tile on the top corner then we have a neighbour above the tile

                if (i > 0)
                {
                    if (j < max)
                    {
                        virtualBoard[i][j].CreateNeighbour(virtualBoard[i - 1][j + rowOffset], Direction.UpperLeft);
                    }
                    if (j >= min && j + rowOffset < virtualBoard[i - 1].Length)
                    {
                       virtualBoard[i][j].CreateNeighbour(virtualBoard[i - 1][j + rowOffset], Direction.UpperRight);
                    }

                    if (j - lowerOffset[i] == 0)
                    {                      
                            virtualBoard[i][j].CreateNeighbour(virtualBoard[i - 1][(j + lowerOffset[i])], Direction.UpperLeft);
                    }
                    if (j - lowerOffset[i] == 0)
                    {                    
                        virtualBoard[i][j].CreateNeighbour(virtualBoard[i - 1][(j - lowerOffset[i])], Direction.UpperRight);
                    }

                }
//if its not the last tile on the bottom corner then the tile has a neighbour below

                if (i < virtualBoard.Length - 1)
                {

                    if (j - lowerOffset[i] == 1)
                    {
                        virtualBoard[i][j].CreateNeighbour(virtualBoard[i + 1][j - (upperOffset[i] - 1)], Direction.LowerLeft);
                    }
                    if (j - lowerOffset[i] == 0)
                    {
                        virtualBoard[i][j].CreateNeighbour(virtualBoard[i + 1][j - (upperOffset[i] - 1)], Direction.LowerRight);
                    }

                }
//if its not the last tile on the left side, the tile has a neighbour on its left side.


                if (j > 0)
                {
                    virtualBoard[i][j].CreateNeighbour(virtualBoard[i][j - 1], Direction.Left);
                }

//if its not the last tile on the right ride, the tile has a neighbour on its right side.


                if (j < virtualBoard[i].Length - 1)
                {
                    virtualBoard[i][j].CreateNeighbour(virtualBoard[i][j + 1], Direction.Right);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I get is **Array index is out of range** and I honestly dont know how to solve this bit...

Hope its not too messy to understand, have tried looking everywhere to something similar and didn't find anything...

Comment: Which line do you get the error on?

Comment: With the given code, the easiest way to find the error is to step through in the debugger and figure out which line is breaking, which variable is causing the break and what you expect it to be vs. what it is. Alternatively, you can probably implement the board as a graph and encapsulate the relationships with tested and documented algorithms. A couple links that might be interesting: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~iliano/courses/17F-CMU-CS122/handouts/23-graphs.pdf, https://exceptionnotfound.net/solving-minesweeper-with-c-sharp-and-linq/

Comment: You can help us a lot by telling us what line the error is on. Click on the error message in Unity console and it should show a stack trace with line numbers. Without that info I suspect this question is not worth trying to answer.

Comment: @GrandMasterFlush the lines of 139 to 157, that would be when Im trying to assign the tiles their neighbours in the direction upper left, upper right etc. Dont know how to show the numbers here in the post.